# Where is "or" generated from, as in "Sign In or Create An Account"

Tags: magento2, html, toplinks

Does anyone know where "or" is generated from, as in "Sign In or Create An Account" in the bar at the top of every page?  It does not appear to be part of either link, just placed there to separate them.  I simply want to remove "or" from every page.

I am using Magento CE version 2.0.7-0 on an offline Linux home test server, with the Luma theme.  The install was from a Bitnami package download.

My folder structures, in part, are like this:
/home/krang/magento-2.0.7-0/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/

I have been able to remove "Sign In" and "Create An Account" in their respective files:

```
return $this->isLoggedIn() ? __('Sign Out') : __('Sign In');

<referenceBlock name="register-link" remove="true"/>
```

I have tried both

```
<referenceBlock name="authorization-link" remove="true"/>
```

and

```
<referenceBlock name="authorization-link-login" remove="true"/>
```

to no avail.

I have also tried Developer debug and numerous searches, but none of them panned out.

“or” appears to be called a data-label, but I haven't been able to find out where this comes from:

```
<li class="authorization-link" data-label="or">
```

Thanks everyone.

Comment: How do people find solutions to such problem? Why do I feel like there is this mysterious guide that explains everything and I'm missing out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's defined in the data-label attribute of the li in the template:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.0/app/code/Magento/Customer/view/frontend/templates/account/link/authorization.phtml#L15

It seems to be rendered by a js function. If you remove the data-label attribute, the `or` should be gone

Comment: Thank you for taking a look and providing the answer.  It worked.

Comment: This puzzled me a couple of months ago. Now I found your answer by accident. Thank you. Do you provide mentor service? I'm willing to compensate you to give me hints and directions into solving such problems.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually a css :after property that draws from the data-label attribute.

From luma's _module.less:

```
> .authorization-link {
                    &:after {
                        content: attr(data-label);
                        display: inline-block;
                        margin: 0 -@indent__xs 0 @indent__xs;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Thank you for taking a look, but David Verholen's guidance worked for me, and he answered first, but I will take a look at what  you posted also, because I heard that we shouldn't modify the .phtml files unless we have to.  If the method you provided works for me, and if I am allowed to , I will uptick your answer.

Comment: You definitely should not modify a base .phtml file. The correct approach is to overwrite it within your theme or module. Same goes for .less files.

Comment: this is actually a good addition to my answer